# How parse raw json list of data posted in ktor

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I'm posting json array of objects. I'm trying to parse it in code like this

```
val objs = call.receive<List<MyClass>>() // this work fine
val name objs[0].name // this throw exception LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to MyClass
```

In above code second line throws exception `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to MyClass`

If i post simple object and parse it in ktor with  `call.receive<MyClass>()` then it will work fine. So issue is only when parsing list of objects.

Answer (score 6):

Using your code with `Array` instead of `List` worked for me using ktor v1.2.3:

```
val objs = call.receive<Array<MyClass>>() 
val name = objs[0].name
```

Side Note:

I later changed my data class to this format to help with mapping from database rows to a data class (i.e. to use BeanPropertyRowMapper). I don't remember this having an effect on de/serialization, but if the first part still isn't working for you, you may try this...

```
data class MyClass(
    var id: Int? = null,
    var name: String? = null,
    var description: String? = null,
)
```

Reference: [Kotlin data class optional variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47134138/3806701)

Comment: This had been working but after updating ktor to v1.2.3 from v1.1.3 no longer works..

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this

```
val json = call.receive<String>()
val objs = Gson().fromJson(json, Array<MyClass>::class.java)
objs[0].name
```

**Updated**

You can also create extention function for that like this

```
suspend inline fun <reified T> ApplicationCall.safeReceive(): T {
    val json = this.receiveOrNull<String>()
    return Gson().fromJson(json, T::class.java)
}
```

then use it like this

```
val objs = call.safeReceive<Array<MyClass>>()
objs[0].name
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply i will try it. It seems parsing manually if possible without doing it that would be better but its better than not work. Thanks agian

Comment: What if we want to return a list.