# Initialise data class object to 1 or 2 arguements in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, data-class

I have the below data class

```
data class ApiPost(
@SerializedName("LoginId")  var userName: String,
@SerializedName("Password") var password: String,
@SerializedName("NewPassword") var newPassword: String,
@SerializedName("FileType") var FileType: String,
@SerializedName("UserId") var UserId: String,
@SerializedName("CountryId") var CountryId: String,
@SerializedName("DateOfBirth") var DateOfBirth: String,
@SerializedName("Mobile") var Mobile: String,
@SerializedName("CountryName") var CountryName: String,
@SerializedName("CompanyName") var CompanyName: String,
@SerializedName("IsAnonymous") var IsAnonymous: String,
@SerializedName("EmployeeIssue") var EmployeeIssue: String,
@SerializedName("DetailedInformation") var DetailedInformation: String,
@SerializedName("EmployeeId") var EmployeeId: String,
@SerializedName("EmployeeEmailId") var EmployeeEmailId: String,
@SerializedName("FCMId") var FCMId: String
)
```

To initialise the object I will have to pass all the values.

But my question is what if I only want to pass 2 values to object. How can that be done?

```
val apiPost: ApiPost=ApiPost()
                    apiPost!!.userName = "ak@gmail.com"
                    apiPost!!.password = "12345"
```

What needs to be done here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47134138/kotlin-data-class-optional-variable

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391468/can-kotlin-data-class-have-more-than-one-constructor Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answer over here 
[Kotlin data class optional variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47134138/kotlin-data-class-optional-variable)

Initialised default value to the data class

```
data class ApiPost(
        @SerializedName("LoginId")  var userName: String ="",
        @SerializedName("Password") var password: String ="",
        @SerializedName("NewPassword") var newPassword: String ="",
        @SerializedName("FileType") var FileType: String ="",
        @SerializedName("UserId") var UserId: String ="",
        @SerializedName("CountryId") var CountryId: String ="",
        @SerializedName("DateOfBirth") var DateOfBirth: String ="",
        @SerializedName("Mobile") var Mobile: String ="",
        @SerializedName("CountryName") var CountryName: String ="",
        @SerializedName("CompanyName") var CompanyName: String ="",
        @SerializedName("IsAnonymous") var IsAnonymous: String ="",
        @SerializedName("EmployeeIssue") var EmployeeIssue: String ="",
        @SerializedName("DetailedInformation") var DetailedInformation: String ="",
        @SerializedName("EmployeeId") var EmployeeId: String ="",
        @SerializedName("EmployeeEmailId") var EmployeeEmailId: String ="",
        @SerializedName("FCMId") var FCMId: String =""
    )
```

And called it as

```
ApiPost(userName = "ak@gmail.com", password = "12345")
```